# PowerShell - matching a regex against threadjob output works but doesn't populate $matches variable

Tags: regex, powershell, azure-cli, powershell-jobs

When I run the following script from a newly opened PowerShell console, the loop exits so there is clearly a match, but the $matches variable (and thus $matches.PORT) is not populated the first time around. When the script is run again, it is populated.

**./ssh.ps1**

```
$BLOCK = { az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription <MY-SUBSCRIPTION> --resource-group <RESOURCE-GROUP> -n <NAME> }
$global:CONNECTION = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $BLOCK

$done = 0
$match_string = ".*Opening tunnel on port: (?<PORT>\d{1,5})\b.*"

while ($done -lt 1) {
    if ($CONNECTION.HasMoreData)
    {
        $DATA = Receive-Job $CONNECTION 2>&1
        
        if ($DATA -match $match_string)
        {
            $port = $matches.PORT
            Write-Output "Connection open on port $port."
            $done = 1
        }
    }
}
Write-Output "Loop ended."
exit
```

Output in the PowerShell console is:

```
PS <LOCAL-DIR>> ./ssh
Connection open on port .
Loop ended.
PS <LOCAL-DIR>> ./ssh
Connection open on port 63182.
Loop ended.
```

By contrast, when I try running the following script, $matches is populated the first time it is run.

**./match.ps1**

```
$string1 = "hello, hello, you big beautiful world of wonder!"
$match_str = ".*\b(?<gotcha>world)\b.*"

$done = 0

while ($done -lt 1)
{
    if ($string1 -match $match_str)
    {
        write-output "Matches:"
        write-output $matches
        
        $done = 1
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PS <LOCAL-DIR>> ./match
Matches:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
gotcha                         world
0                              hello, hello, you big beautiful world of wonder!
```

If anyone can fathom why the text is matched in the first script without $matches being populated I would be incredibly grateful.

P.S.
The script existing after the loop is just for investigative purposes and not what my code will actually do.

P.P.S.
For reference, the output from `az webapp create-remote-connection`, after a delay whilst connecting, is:

```
Verifying if app is running....
App is running. Trying to establish tunnel connection...
Opening tunnel on port: 63341
SSH is available { username: root, password: Docker! }
Ctrl + C to close
```

(The port varies each time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) *isn't* populated after a [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation, the implication is that the LHS operand was a *collection* rather than a *single string*.

Therefore, *loop over* the value of `$DATA` and match each line individually:

```
foreach ($line in $DATA) {
  if ($line -match $match_string)
  {
    $port = $matches.PORT
    "Connection open on port $port."
    $done = 1
    break
  }
}
```

By design:

- `$Matches` is only populated if the LHS is a *string* (scalar).
- With a *collection* (array) as the LHS, `-match` - as many comparison operators do - acts as a *filter* and returns the (potentially empty) *sub-array of matching elements*.
- Any *prior* `$Matches` value is *preserved* if *either* a given string-scalar `-match` operation happens not to find a match *or* its LHS is a *collection*.

Comment: Thanks - had just been experimenting just now and discovered that the first time the script is run, $DATA is multiline, whereas for some reason all subsequent runs seem to be a single-line string. Have now added a foreach loop to my logic and all is working now.